# Show a prompt before page gets refreshed in mobile safari

Tags: mobile, safari, refresh, prompt

Is it possible in mobile safari to get notified when the user clicks on refresh button. I want to prevent users from accidentally leaving the page as they might have some unsaved data on the page.
I have a code that shows a prompt in safari desktop but for touch safari it just does not show anything and refreshes the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an alternative method to use onbeforeunload in mobile safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205989/is-there-an-alternative-method-to-use-onbeforeunload-in-mobile-safari)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you did is something like this?

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    return "You have unsaved stuff";
});
```

​
It seems it doesn't work in mobile Safari

See this possible duplicate: [Is there an alternative method to use onbeforeunload in mobile safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205989/is-there-an-alternative-method-to-use-onbeforeunload-in-mobile-safari)