# How can I ask users to confirm before leaving the page on iOS safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, onbeforeunload, confirm

I now have:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmFirst;

function confirmFirst() {   
  return "Leave the page?"; 
}
```

This can give users a prompt to confirm that they are leaving the page on all major browsers, except on iOS safari. How can I make it work?

I want to implement this as my users often accidentally swipe right (back button) and left the page after typing in some long paragraphs on my site. Thank you!

Comment: This is really bad from IOS devices. Such an important event(onunload, pagehide) to track key information before leaving the page. #ios-bugs

Answer (score 1):

<strike>What's wrong with your code right now? That should do the job...


You can do this using either regular JS:</strike>

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return 'Leave the page?';
};
```

Or even jQuery:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){   
  return 'Leave the page?'; 
});
```

Is this useful?
[Is there an alternative method to use onbeforeunload in mobile safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205989/is-there-an-alternative-method-to-use-onbeforeunload-in-mobile-safari)

Comment: Assuming iOS safari respects the beforeunload event - which it does not. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5

Comment: Yeah I looked over the iOS part.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205989/is-there-an-alternative-method-to-use-onbeforeunload-in-mobile-safari

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onbeforeunload = confirmFirst;

function confirmFirst() {   
  if(confirm("Leave the page?")){
    // some code
  }else{
   return false;
  } 
}
```

Comment: What's with the random jQuery reference?