# How gmail handle its onbeforeunload event in opera?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I'm looking for something similar to gmail on how it handle the onbeforeunload event in Opera. As we know opera doesn't support onbeforeunload event. But when I compose a new message on gmail using opera browser and navigate to other page like inbox, gmail save the message automatically into draft's folder.

Anyone know how gmail handle this kind of event?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390260/onbeforeunload-in-opera

Comment: Is it saving specifically in response to your navigation, or just periodically saving regardless? Also, if you're navigating _within_ gmail via their own links/buttons then they can do whatever they like in response - what happens if you type a different address (say yahoo.com) into the address bar?