# Detecting changes in window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect changes in window.location (for example to be notified if the user tries to reload the page) but I can't seem to find a way to do that.
Are there some events associated with it?

Thanks

Comment: [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `unload` event is fired when the user leaves the page. There's also a `beforeunload` event in some browsers, but it's [not supported in Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4509078/238978).

Comment: I didn't find anything just by searching on the web wrong keywords I guess. Awkward!
By the way, thanks a lot!

Comment: abuduba, thanks, I didn't know that. I've added that info to my answer!