# Log changes in window.location

Tags: javascript

Communication between Sketchup and their webdialogs is done by using `window.location = skp:action@value` to trigger a callback on the Sketchup. While doing so, it doesn't load another page, which [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070968/detecting-changes-in-window-location) uses.

Is there a way to extend window.location to log changes to the console when it doesn't load a new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the `hashchange` event that fires when a window's hash changes

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange

```
window
  .addEventListener("hashchange", function(event){
    console.log(event.newURL); //document.URL
  }, false);
```