# How to alert user to not close the window while he has submitted the form to process?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript To Get An Alert When Closing The Browser Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333665/javascript-to-get-an-alert-when-closing-the-browser-window)

I am having a site on which users are visiting and uploading video, in that i am having a problem that users are closing the browsers or navigating from the page without letting the upload process to complete, i want to show a alert box to the user to not close the window or not to navigate from the page when uploading process is going on, i tried it through window.unload but it will not work for me because as the uploading process is going on the page will be submitted so that event will always be called, please tell me the way to show the alert box to users on window close or they navigate from the page.

Thanks in advance,
Ravinder Singh

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use:

```
window.onbeforeunload
```

Comment: @user917197 the return value will be the message in the box!

Comment: it will not work because it will show the alert even user didn't attempt to close the browser.