# How can I generate an alert/pop-up saying avoid clicking back button of browser before user clicks it

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I have disabled the back button in my application,I want user not to click it (across all browsers).

Comment: This post may help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333665/javascript-to-get-an-alert-when-closing-the-browser-window

Answer (score 0):

> $('.button').hover(function(){
>
> alert("This button is not working");
>
> });

but you might like to just change the HREF of it, to `href="#"`, after clicking nothing will happen.