# Differentiate browser refresh and browser close

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I want to set a cookie when a visitor on the page closes the browser.
I used onbeforeunload method like this

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    return "You have attempted to leave this page.  If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost.  Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
  }
</script>
```

followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333665/javascript-to-get-an-alert-when-closing-the-browser-window)

But found out that even refresh of page or click on any hyper link on the page,pops up an alert.

I need to set cookie only when visitor clicks cross button of browser and not on page refresh.

I followed some of the links like the one above and another [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?202588-refresh-or-close). And found from the post that we can not differentiate between close and refresh. But those posts were 3-4 years back.

Is there is any way to differentiate these events using JavaScript or Jquery?

Comment: Nope. Or at least not that I know.

Comment: What do you mean by, Cross button of browser?

Comment: @Gacnt : I mean closing the browser by clicking cross

Comment: And what about Ctrl-x, navigate with the address bar, bookmark, etc. It is impossible!

Comment: Why does the cookie need to be set on exactly that occasion to begin with? Chances are there's a much better way to do whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: use property of localStorage and sessionStorage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identifying Between Refresh And Close Browser Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568977/identifying-between-refresh-and-close-browser-actions)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you have no way to tell.

The only thing you can do is overload clicks on links and set a flag. But you can never know if it is a refresh or a close...

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, what about this:

1. Set a cookie onbeforeunload
2. Globally onload, check the timestamp of the cookie to see whether this was a link, or a new session
3. If the timestamp difference is only a few seconds, delete the cookie

Comment: Well, ye it's a bit dirty but you don't have much choice... You could combined that with my answer.

Comment: @Maresh No argument here; dirty indeed.  There's probably a better way to solve the problem, but this is the only solution I could think of for the *question* ;)

Comment: No, as I said he doesn't have much choice. I'm sorry you took it the wrong way, this is a good solution.

Comment: Didn't take it wrong--you had a point about its lack of cleanliness.

Comment: Good then :) And I think you deserve a +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, unload is called when browser is closed and onload is called when you try to reload. You can use these properties and set flags , and fire events accordingly

[Browser close and reload](https://webkul.com/blog/detect-browser-tab-refresh-browser-tab-close-using-javascript/) Check this link for more details