# Trigger function or event when closing browser tab using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to trigger a function when a using closes the browser tab and prevent it from closing instead a popup will ask the user to proceed to other page or continue to close the browser page?

Scenario:

When the user closes the browser tab of a page, then it wont close right away instead a custom popup (possibly html popup) will prompt and ask if continue to close or proceed to other page. So it would have 2 buttons, "Close" and "Proceed to Page".

If it's not possible using HTML popup, prompt would be fine too. But it should be crossbrowser.

By the way, i prefer using Javascript.. So that's my ideal script to make this function work

Thanks :)

Comment: Like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333665/javascript-to-get-an-alert-when-closing-the-browser-window

Comment: You shouldn't do that really, it's a horrible spammy why of making people not leave your site.

Comment: Did any of the answers below help you?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `onbeforeunload`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Are you sure you wish to leave the page?";
}
```

Just know that you will really annoy your visitors if you do this, it is strongly disliked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     var popit = true;
     window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
      if(popit == true) {
           popit = false;
           return "Are you sure you want to leave?"; 
      }
 }
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SQAmG/3/)**